# Could not load type 'MediatR.ServiceFactory'

Tags: .net-6.0, mediatr

I'm creating an Api and I am also using mediatR, I have created my commands, queries, handlers, but when I try to launch my Api I get this error message in my program class:

```
Could not load type 'MediatR.ServiceFactory' from assembly 'MediatR, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=bb9a41a5e8aaa7e2'.
```

I'm registering my mediatR in my program class like this:

```
builder.Services.AddMediatR(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

I have installed the MediatR (latest version: 12.0.0) and the MediatR.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection (version: 11.0.0 ) because the latest version(11.1.0) at this moment is deprecated.
[image]

I'm using .Net 6, any possible solution? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The update to MediatR 12 comes with a Migration Guide [here](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/wiki/Migration-Guide-11.x-to-12.0).

To solve your issue, replace

```
builder.Services.AddMediatR(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
```

with

```
services.AddMediatR(cfg=>cfg.RegisterServicesFromAssemblies(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));
```

If you have a handler from another (single) assembly, you can try this:

```
 services.AddMediatR(cfg=>cfg.RegisterServicesFromAssemblies(typeof(MyCoolThingInAnotherAssemblyRequestHandler).GetTypeInfo().Assembly));
```

To use any of the above extension methods..you may need to add:

```
using MediatR;
```

From Migration guide

> Service registration through configuration object exclusively
> Service registration through IServiceCollection previously had overloads for various options. These are now consolidated into the single MediatrServiceConfiguration object. Overloads that passed through the assemblies to scan need to register using methods on this configuration object instead:

Answer (score 9):

If anyone using Autofac comes across this post, convert the deprecated `ServiceFactory` registration

```
builder.Register<ServiceFactory>(ctx =>
{
  var c = ctx.Resolve<IComponentContext>();
  return t => c.Resolve(t);
});
```

to a populated `ServiceCollection` based on the [following example](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR/blob/4c3ef702a3c64dc3a5adc131c4c2480107324a80/samples/MediatR.Examples.Autofac/Program.cs)

```
var services = new ServiceCollection();
        
builder.Populate(services);
```

Comment: Thanks. This is what I was looking for. I'm using the clean architecture template from ardalis and it's using this setup.

Answer (score 3):

It is very simple. In order to solve your problem just add the following line in your Program.cs class.

```
builder.Services.AddMediatR(x => x.RegisterServicesFromAssemblies(typeof(LibraryEntrypoint).Assembly));
```

here **"LibraryEntrypoint"** is an empty class created in the project folder, this is created to just refer to the assembly of my project. You can add any of the class if you wish.

```
internal class LibraryEntrypoint
{

}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it turned out that different versions of the MediatR nuget package were being used. In one assembly, it was `<PackageReference Include="MediatR" Version="10.0.1" />`, and in another, `<PackageReference Include="MediatR" Version="12.1.1" />`
The solution is to make the used nuget packages the same version.